# Using ApplicationMailer, Receiving undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this defined in my `application_mailer.rb`

```
  def request_tutor(contact_name, contact_hp, contact_email, postal_code, contact_level, contact_subject, contact_lessons, contact_hours, contact_others)
    @contact_name = contact_name
    @contact_hp = contact_hp
    @contact_email = contact_email
    @contact_postal = postal_code
    @contact_level = contact_level
    @contact_subject = contact_subject
    @contact_lesson = contact_lessons
    @contact_hours = contact_hours
    @contact_others = contact_others
    mail(to:'example@example.com', subject: 'Tutor Request')
  end
```

and in the respective controller where the view is supposed to be rendered

```
  def request_tutor
      contact_name = params[:request_tutor][:contact_name]
      contact_email = params[:request_tutor][:contact_email]
      contact_hp = params[:request_tutor][:contact_hp]
      contact_postal = params[:request_tutor][:postal_code]
      contact_level = params[:request_tutor][:contact_level]
      contact_subject = params[:request_tutor][:contact_subject]
      contact_lesson = params[:request_tutor][:contact_lessons]
      contact_hours = params[:request_tutor][:contact_hours]
      contact_others = params[:request_tutor][:contact_others]
      ApplicationMailer.request_tutor(contact_name, contact_hp, contact_email, postal_code, contact_level, contact_subject, contact_lessons, contact_hours, contact_others).deliver
      flash[:success] = "We have received your request and will be in touch with you shortly!"
      redirect_to root_path
   end
```

I have a similar method setup in action mailer too and in the respective controller i'm doing `name = params[:checkout][:your_name]` and it doesn't return the error `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`. What am i missing?

Errors from `development.log`

```
Started GET "/" for 116.87.14.150 at 2016-10-10 23:02:37 +0000
Cannot render console from 116.87.14.150! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (390.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (5.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 641ms (Views: 608.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/welcome/request" for 116.87.14.150 at 2016-10-10 23:02:43 +0000
Cannot render console from 116.87.14.150! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by WelcomeController#request_tutor as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:16:in `request_tutor'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (6.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (110.0ms)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This will happen if `params[:request_tutor]` is blank (or `params[:checkout]` - you use both in your question). Have a look in your server logs (in `log/development.log` or your terminal window) and see if you can find the error message there... then look at the lines nearby to it (usually just above) - which should show you the `params` that got sent to the server when the request was submitted - it's possible that your `params` aren't being sent through in quite the way you are expecting.

Comment: The interesting thing is that `params[:checkout]` works which is why i'm quite puzzled as to why it isn't working now. It was setup according to the application mailer segment from guides.rubyonrails.org. I followed the same steps for both but one is working and one isn't.

Comment: Cool... sooo.. can you look in your server logs like I asked :) That will help us pinpoint the issue (which might not be in the code you've showed us, but in the code that sets up the params to send it)

Comment: This is the only relevant error i see in my rails console `NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:16:in 'request_tutor'`

i am using an IDE and they aren't letting me open my development.log because the file is over 8MB.

Comment: Ok, so I'd recommend: a) stopping the rails server b) deleting the `log/development.log`  c) restarting the rails server again d) run your request again. That will start a new logfile and it'll be short enough for you to open it - you hardly ever look in the log anyway and it doesn't matter if you delete it as it's just on your dev machine right?

Comment: I've done as you said and copy and pasted it into my original question.

Comment: Ok, so what's clear from the logs is that you aren't getting any params at all with this request: `GET "/welcome/request"` That means that your `params[:request_tutor]` will fail... so... what's the template that you are using for your `/welcome/request` action? Do you have the equivalent of a pair of actions eg like `new/create` ? if so... you need to make sure you don't require all the params to be present for the `new`-equivalent action or it'll break before you even get to see the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125378/discussion-between-angkiki-and-taryn-east).

Comment: No, sorry I hate chat. :( I am doing actual work in between popping in here and answering these questions while I'm on break or running a test suite... asynchronous communication is better for me.

Comment: Okay i'm so sorry about that. In my routes.rb i'm using `get 'welcome/request', to: 'welcome#request_tutor'` and in the actual view i'm rendering a `<%= form_for :request_tutor, :url => welcome_request_tutor_path do |f| %>`

Comment: No problems - i know some people love chat - but in this case it's ok because we're debugging :) I've added a potential solution to your problem as an answer below - see if it fixes your problem (at least until the next bug - when we can start up a new question) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so you are using the same action to both set up the form, and also to create the email. This is where the problem comes in... because when you first click on the form - it will run the `request_tutor` action, but there is no `params[:request_tutor]` yet (because you haven't submitted the form yet)... so you need to check for that to exist before trying to create one.

eg this is possible:

```
def request_tutor
  if params[:request_tutor].present?
    contact_name = params[:request_tutor][:contact_name]
    # ... lines skipped for brevity
    # you still need the ones in your original action
    ApplicationMailer.request_tutor(contact_name, contact_hp, contact_email, postal_code, contact_level, contact_subject, contact_lessons, contact_hours, contact_others).deliver
    flash[:success] = "We have received your request and will be in touch with you shortly!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  # If the code gets to here, there were no params, and the page
  # will just render the template named the same as the action
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. Guess it didn't occur to me to check for `params.present`.

Comment: No probs :) we all learned this stuff at one point or another :)